# Variables on PHP explode set to 1 character?

Tags: php, explode

I am trying to post 3 variables via a Checkbox.

If a user ticks a Checkbox for each product, I am trying to send 3 variables:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="'. $rowAttr["reference"] .'-'. $rowAttr["price"] .'-'. $rowProd["unity"] .'">
```

The variables are definitely set as I have printed them all to the page where the user can see what Product they are selecting. However, when they submit the form, the variables from the checkbox are set to 1 characters? Where is this going wrong?

```
$selected = explode('-', $product);
$reference = $selected[0];
$price = $selected[1];
$unity = $selected[2];

echo '<table class="table table-striped">';
    echo '<th>Product Reference</th><th>Price</th><th>Unit</th>';
        if(isset($_POST['product'])) {
            foreach($_POST['product'] as $product) {
                print '<tr>';
                    print '<td>'. $product['reference'] .'</td>';
                    print '<td>'. $product['price'] .'</td>';
                    print '<td>'. $product['unity'] .'</td>';
                print '</tr>';
            }
        }
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: What exactly is `$product` in your above code? And why are you trying to send values like the price of an item via the form anyway? That information should be kept on the server, unless you want users to be able to manipulate it (which in a shopping cart situation you most of the times rather don’t.)

Answer (score 1):

try to run the code below

```
   $product = $_POST['product'];
   echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($product);
   echo "</pre>";
```

I think your array  look like this

```
  array(3){
   [0]=>array(3) {[0]=>"some value",[1]=>"some value",[2]=>"some value",}

   [1]=>array(3) {[0]=>"some value",[1]=>"some value",[2]=>"some value",}

   [2]=>array(3) {[0]=>"some value",[1]=>"some value",[2]=>"some value",}
   }
```

So do foreah or call `$product[0][1], $product[0][2], $product[0][3]`
instead.

Comment: it's NULL? Why would that be?

Comment: man did you run  `$product = $_POST['product ']` before everything?

Comment: You mean `var_dump`

Comment: oh my careless mistake